# Curvature measure for polygones on a 2D space

Tags: geometry, curvature, polygons

I would like to implement a curvature measure for polygones on a 2D space. My goal is to compute shape parameters to know if the polygon is close to a circle or has a sinuous shape or an elongated shape...

I already try to fit to various shapes, compute parameters based on length, area or perimeter so I would rather focus on angles or curvatures but both inspiration and Google failed me.

- I already have a measure based on perimeter to area ratio which is probably very correlated to a mean radius of curvature, I am looking for a different perspective.
- I know a curvature measure for continuous functions (defined here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvature#Curvature_of_a_graph). That would probably be interesting if I could see how to implement it for a polygone with discontinuous derivatives at summits.
- I can imagine something similar to an energy cost that would penalize narrow angles, concavities... But I don't see how to translate it mathematically.

I would be glad if you have ideas or precise measure definitions I could apply to this problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wrote up some notes a few years ago on how to approximate the curvature of discrete plane curves. There are several potential formulas, depending on the precise properties you are interested in: http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/evouga/uploads/4/5/6/8/45689883/notes1.pdf

Comment: This paper suggests 3 differents curvature measures. How would you sum them to compute a cost ? I need to penalize concavities so my first guess would be to add absolute values or square of values.
Thanks.

Comment: Yes I would use the sum of squared curvatures as an energy. Physically this is the same energy as controls the shape of e.g. a rubber cable

Answer (score 3):

This is a vast area of research. Here is a classification of approaches, taken from p.9 of "Curvature Variation as Measure of Shape Information," by
S.R. Sukumar:

---

[image: Zhang2004]

          

<sup>([PDF download](http://trace.tennessee.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=3832&context=utk_gradthes) of Sukumar's thesis.)</sup>

---

A nice survey is:

> Veltkamp, Remco C. "Shape matching: Similarity measures and algorithms." *Shape Modeling and Applications*, IEEE, 2001. ([PDF download](http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~kreve101/asci/smi2001.pdf).)

Comment: While I have found many of my shape parameters in scientific articles, most were defined with a simple formula. Some others were not defined explicitly but it was easy to do it myself.
Curvature was not in these papers and it's more complicated than I had imagined (despite I spent time thinking of a definition).
Please before I vote, give me time to read the documents you were kind to provide.